# How to build a docker image that requires other images / ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i want to build a docker image that contains my app. the build process (test phase) requires a database. when i build the app (without the docker image) i just start the db locally:

```
docker run -ti --rm --name postgres -p 5432:5432 postgres:10.9-alpine
```

and then i build the app. but when i build the app from my dockerfile, it can't connect to local database.

how can i allow my docker build to see the db? do i have to use docker-compose to build my app? or can it somehow connect to my local db?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

- legacy docker linking
- Docker-compose network

`--link <name or id>`

So you can link with DB like this

```
docker run -d -P --name web --link db:db  your_appp
```

Now your app can connect with DB using host name `db`.

Now

> Warning: The `--link` flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may
>   eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using
>   it.

https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

In the above case can reach DB using hostname `db`.

If you want to connect at build time of Dockerfile, then you need to use host IP and also you need to publish DB port as well.